# How is a header only ANSI C library possible?

Tags: c

There is a very popular library named [nuklear](https://github.com/vurtun/nuklear) that is both written in ANSI C and entirely header only. However, there can only be one definition of functions in each translation unit, and ANSI C does not have `inline` functions, so how does this library work properly without linker errors?

Comment: C99 does have `inline`, and pretty much every C89 compiler has it as an extension. Also: `static`.

Comment: Why not take a look at the source code?

Comment: Pretty sure `inilne` was added in C99.

Comment: Well, firstly, modern C does have `inline`. But even without `inline` you can just declare every function `static`... Another option would be to use something platform-specific, like weak symbols (if you, say, need global variables).

Comment: ... but most importantly, looking at the src directory reveals that it's all but header only... Just look at how many .c files are under there.

Comment: @MatteoItalia After reading through a bit of the source code, they rely on no compiler extensions for inlining functions.

Comment: @MatteoItalia There is also a single_include directory.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Starting at line 73 is a description on how to use this header:

```
/// ## Usage
/// This library is self contained in one single header file and can be used either
/// in header only mode or in implementation mode. The header only mode is used
/// by default when included and allows including this header in other headers
/// and does not contain the actual implementation. <br /><br />
///
/// The implementation mode requires to define  the preprocessor macro
/// NK_IMPLEMENTATION in *one* .c/.cpp file before #includeing this file, e.g.:
///
/// ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~C
///     #define NK_IMPLEMENTATION
///     #include "nuklear.h"
/// ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

So normally including this header file will only give you the declarations.  If you `#define NK_IMPLEMENTATION` before including, then the implementation is included.